# How can I plot shapefile loaded through fastshp in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I stumbled upon [fastshp](http://www.rforge.net/fastshp/index.html) library and according to description (and my quick cursory tests) it really does offer improvements in time of reading large shapefiles compared to [three other methods](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles).

I'm using `read.shp` function to load exemplary dataset from maptools package:

```
library("maptools")

setwd(system.file("shapes", package="maptools"))

shp <- read.shp("columbus.shp", format="polygon")
```

I chose 'polygon' format since accordng to [docs](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/fastshp/html/read.shp.html):

> This is typically the preferred format for plotting.

My question is how can I plot these polygons using ggplot2 package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `read.shp` in the `fastshp` package returns the polygon data in the form of a list of lists, it is then a matter of reducing it to a single dataframe required for plotting in `ggplot2`.

```
library(fastshp)
library(ggplot2)

setwd(system.file("shapes", package="maptools"))

shp <- read.shp("columbus.shp", format="polygon")
shp.list <- sapply(shp, FUN = function(x) do.call(cbind, x[c("id","x","y")]))
shp.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, shp.list))
shp.gg <- ggplot(shp.df, aes(x = x, y=y, group = id))+geom_polygon()
```

EDIT: Based on @otsaw's comment regarding polygon holes, the following solution requires a couple of more steps but ensures that the holes are plotted last.  It takes advantage that shp.df$hole is logical and polygons with hole==TRUE will be plotted last.

```
shp.list <- sapply(shp, FUN = function(x) Polygon(cbind(lon = x$x, lat = x$y)))
shp.poly <- Polygons(shp.list, "area")
shp.df <- fortify(shp.poly, region = "area")
shp.gg <- ggplot(shp.df, aes(x = long, y=lat, group = piece, order = hole))+geom_polygon()
```

Comment: @otsaw: I've added an alternate approach that will render holes correctly

Comment: @JimM. this is a great solution but unfortunately no longer works. Is there an alternative workflow to obtain the correctly formatted data.frame? Just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741003/plotting-shape-files-loaded-using-read-shp-with-ggplot2

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian: Nowadays, I would probably go with the sf package (i.e. read shapefiles via st_read), which can be plotted with ggplot with geom_sf : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf5.html#ggplot2

Comment: @JimM. Yep, my go to for years was `rgdal` and more recently `sf` given as you mentioned the `geom_sf` in `ggplot2` but I currently lack access to installing non-R dependencies and needed a solution that didn't rely on gdal or C libraries used by `sf`

Comment: @JimM. checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741003/plotting-shape-files-loaded-using-read-shp-with-ggplot2?noredirect=1#comment105668527_59741003 for a solution if you're interested!