# Plotting shape files loaded using read.shp with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, spatial

I would like to plot a shape file loaded using read.shp from the `fastshp` package. However, the `read.shp` function returns a list of list and not a data.frame. I'm unsure which part of the list I need to extract to obtain the correctly formatted data.frame object. This exact question has been asked on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306831/how-can-i-plot-shapefile-loaded-through-fastshp-in-ggplot2?rq=1) already, however, the solution no longer seems to work (solution was from > 7 years ago). Any help is much appreciated.

```
remotes::install_github("s-u/fastshp") #fastshp not on CRAN
library(ggplot2);library(fastshp)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/COUNTY/tl_2017_us_county.zip",temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- list.files(temp2, pattern = ".shp$",full.names=TRUE) %>% read.shp(.)
```

`shp` is a list of lists containing a plethora of information. I tried the following solution from the SO posted earlier, but to no avail:

```
shp.list <- sapply(shp, FUN = function(x) Polygon(cbind(lon = x$x, lat = x$y))) #throws an error here cbind(lon = x$x, lat = x$y) returns NULL
shp.poly <- Polygons(shp.list, "area")
shp.df <- fortify(shp.poly, region = "area")
```

I also tried the following:

```
shp.list <- sapply(shp, FUN = function(x) do.call(cbind, x[c("id","x","y")])) #returns NULL value here...
shp.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, shp.list))
```

**Updated**: Still no luck but closer:

```
file_shp<-list.files(temp2, pattern = ".shp$",full.names=TRUE) %>%
  read.shp(., format = c("table"))

ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = file_shp, aes(x = x, y = y, group = part), 
             colour = "black", fill = NA)
```

[image]

Looks like the projection is off. I'm not sure how to order the data to map correctly, also not sure how to read in the CRS data. Tried the following to no avail:

```
file_prj<-list.files(temp2, pattern = ".prj$",full.names=TRUE) %>%
  proj4string(.)
```

Comment: Any interest in trying [`sf`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/index.html)? It converts between formats well and there's a `geom_sf` for plotting `sf` objects

Comment: @Camille if it doesn't rely on rgdal, I'm open to it. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Unfortunately, `sf` relies on the `units` package, which like `rgdal`, requires additional software to be installed, which I lack the ability to do. So back to square one...

Comment: Oh, bummer. Can you add an example somehow that folks could reproduce? Maybe with shapefiles that ship with one of the packages you can use?

Comment: @Camille just updated using a random shapefile from the net. thanks!

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I was following your code, but R studio crashes when I ran `shp <- list.files(temp2, pattern = ".shp$",full.names=TRUE) %>% read.shp(.)`. I wonder what is causing this issue.

Comment: @jazzurro thank you for running the code. Yea, not sure.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian I just posted what I investigated. Have a look. I hope this guides you through.

Comment: @jazzurro this is fantastic. You really dug deep on this and that's much appreciated.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Pleasure to help you. I had a chance to learn how to draw maps in another way. :) I hope you can keep rolling using this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use the census data you have in your script. However, R Studio somehow kept crashing when I applied `read.shp()` to the polygon data. Hence, I decided to use the example from the help page of `read.shp()`, which is also census data. I hope you do not mind. It took some time to figure out how to draw a map with class shp. Let me explain what I went through step by step.

This part is from the help page. I am basically getting shapefile and importing it as shp object.

```
# Census 2010 TIGER/Line(TM) state shapefile
library(fastshp)
fn <- system.file("shp", "tl_2010_us_state10.shp.xz", package="fastshp")
s <- read.shp(xzfile(fn, "rb"))
```

Let's check how this object, `s` is like. It contains 52 lists. In each list, there are six vectors. `ID` is a unique integer to represent a state. `x` is longitude and `y` is latitude. The nasty part was `parts`. In this example below, there is only one number, which means there is one polygon only in this state. But some other lists (states) have multiple numbers. These numbers are basically indices which indicate where new polygons begin in the data.

```
#> str(s)
#List of 52
# $ :List of 6
#  ..$ id   : int 1
#  ..$ type : int 5
#  ..$ box  : num [1:4] -111 41 -104 45
#  ..$ parts: int 0
#  ..$ x    : num [1:9145] -109 -109 -109 -109 -109 ...
#  ..$ y    : num [1:9145] 45 45 45 45 45 ...
```

Here is the one for Alaska. As you see there are some numbers in `parts` These numbers indicate where new polygon data begin. Alaksa has many small islands. Hence they needed to indicate different polygons in the data with this information. We will come back to this later when we create data frames.

```
#List of 6
# $ id   : int 18
# $ type : int 5
# $ box  : num [1:4] -179.2 51.2 179.9 71.4
# $ parts: int [1:50] 0 52 88 127 175 207 244 306 341 375 ...
# $ x    : num [1:14033] 177 177 177 177 177 ...
# $ y    : num [1:14033] 52.1 52.1 52.1 52.1 52.1 ...
```

What we need is the following. For each list, we need to extract longitude (i.e., `x`), latitude (i.e., `y`), and `id` in order to create a data fame for one state. In addition, we need to use `parts` so that we can indicate all polygons with unique IDs. We need to crate a new group variable, which contains unique ID value for each polygon. I used `findInterval()` which takes indices to create a group variable. One tricky part was that we need to use `left.open = TRUE` in `findInterval()` in order to create a group variable. (This gave me some hard time to figure out what was going on.) This `map_dfr()` part handles the job I just described.

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(.x = s,
        .f = function(mylist){

                temp <- data.frame(id = mylist$id,
                                   lon = mylist$x,
                                   lat = mylist$y)
                ind <- mylist$parts

                out <- mutate(temp,
                              subgroup = findInterval(x = 1:n(), vec = ind, left.open = TRUE),
                              group = paste(id, subgroup, sep = "_"))
                return(out)

                }) -> test
```

Once we have `test`, we have another job. Some longitude points of Alaska stay in positive numbers (e.g., 179.85). As long as we have numbers like this, ggplot2 draws funny long lines, which you can see even in your example. What we need is to convert these positive numbers to negative ones so that ggplot2 can draw a proper map.

```
mutate(test,
       lon = if_else(lon > 0, lon * -1, lon)) -> out
```

By this time, `out` looks like this.

```
  id       lon      lat subgroup group
1  1 -108.6213 45.00028        1   1_1
2  1 -108.6197 45.00028        1   1_1
3  1 -108.6150 45.00031        1   1_1
4  1 -108.6134 45.00032        1   1_1
5  1 -108.6133 45.00032        1   1_1
6  1 -108.6130 45.00032        1   1_1
```

Now we are ready to draw a map.

```
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = out, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = group))
```

[image]